# how to make ssh pass work with two hosts via ssh J

Tags: authentication, ssh, sshpass

As per `$subject`

is there a way that i can use partially automate half of the ssh

USE case

> jumphost => random onetime password via hw (interactive
>
> endhost => known stable password which is authenticated via ldap

As the  `$endhost` can change i cannot push my ssh key.

Any ideas would be highly welcome

======= EDIT with update ============

So we have 40-50 jump servers that utilise yubikey authentication
behind each of those jumpservers are a number of vm's lets say 1000/jump server

As you can understand i cannot push my key to 40k vm's which some of them been containers are volatile hence my key will be dropped eventually.
the yubikey i cant automate for sure i tried emulating keyboard input and failed miserably

Comment: I would check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide more information on your scenario and maybe example of what you have tried.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cannot push my ssh key". Ideally, each endhost would have its own key, which you would forward through the jumphost using `ssh-agent`, keeping the private keys on your local machine.

Comment: How are you getting the random, onetime password? `ssh` might be able to interface directly with it.

Comment: @fizz basically i am trying to migrate the crazines of the ssh proxy to the wrapper that -J is so except trying to use sshpass that failed my mind is stuck.

chepner let me update the description as i can now see its misleading